# Relation between field of two webform

Tags: webforms, views, entities

I have created two webform as Vendor and Sponsors.There is two sponsorship type as gold and platinum in sponsors and each vendor is sponsors. Now i want to show in Vendor view the type of sponsorship this vendor have. Both are separate modules. I am not able to understand how to do this.

Comment: Why do you need this to be webforms? If they were ordinary content types you could use the module entity reference to reference the vendor from the sponsor.

Comment: Actually there are  separate registration form for both vendors and sponsors and i have used web forms for that

Comment: I would consider using regular content types for this instead. Webforms are great for signups, surveys etc. But with real content types you can use modules such as entity reference to build this functionality.

Comment: I am newbie in drupal so i dont have much idea about these concepts early so i have choose webforms for this and now stuck into these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can not reference a webform submission from another webform. The functionality you describe is needed here is something I recommend using standard Drupal content types for.

Create a content type called Vendor and another one called Sponsor. Use the module [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to create a field that describes the reference between the content types.

Webforms are great for simple forms, surveys etc but not in this use case.